# ExtJS 5: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}' using Ext.panel.Panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I created a simple Panel using ExtJS 5.0.1, but dont work. Every time i get the error `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '}'`

```
        var anchura = windowWidth;
        anchura *= 0.970;
        anchura += 1;
        var altura = windowHeight;
        altura *= 0.98;

    panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            id:'ventana',
            autoScroll:true,
            height: altura,
            width: anchura,
            title: '&nbsp;<bean:message key="breadcrumbs.gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple" />',
            iconCls:'vDependencias',
            layout: 'border',
            closable: false,
            renderTo: 'contenedor',
            resizable: false,
            items: ['algo','otro algo'],
            frame: true
        });
```

Comment: what is `items`here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var panel= Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
     id:'ventana',
            autoScroll:true,
            height: altura,
            width: anchura,
            title: '&nbsp;<bean:message key="breadcrumbs.gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple" />',
            iconCls:'vDependencias',
            layout: 'border',
            closable: false,
            renderTo: 'contenedor',
            resizable: false,
            items: [{some type},{some type}],
            frame: true
 });
```

Since you using the default Panel, you are not defining the items correctly.
Refer here for documentation: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-cfg-items

items should either be

> a single item, or an array of child Components to be added to this
>   container

. And components are objects and not strings. 
*You cannot pass an array of strings to the items.*

example:

```
items:[
   {xtype:'button'}, 
   {xtype:'textfield'}
]
```

Otherwise, there is nothing wrong in your construct.

Comment: Thank you, now seems it works (i cant do it render in my div, but is another question).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
panel = new Ext.panel.Panel({
            id:'ventana',
            autoScroll:true,
            height: altura,
            width: anchura,
            title: '&nbsp;<bean:message key="breadcrumbs.gestionInventarios.consultaMultiple" />',
            iconCls:'vDependencias',
            layout: 'border',
            closable: false,
            renderTo: 'contenedor',
            resizable: false,
            items: [variabl1,variabl2 ],
            frame: true
        });
```

This might be root cause of your problem.

Also, please make sure that `altura` and `anchura` variables are declared and error is coming for this panel only..!

Comment: Hi, i added the `anchura` and `altura` variables to the topic. In my code the objects of `items:` will be a formPanel and another Panel but now im using only two strings. I tried with your code but still appearing the same error.

Comment: Assign your another formPanel into variables and use it like I have updated answer.